# "I have no sources to back me up" versus "back myself up"

Tags: grammar, reflexives

In Latin, it is preferable to use the reflexive pronoun when appropriate. Is this also true of English?

For example, I recently wrote this sentence. **"I have no sources to back me up."** Would it be more correct to say, **"I have no sources to back myself up"?**

The first sounds better. But the second looks more grammatical. Of course, I am bringing my Latin biases into the English language. Is my prejudice unfounded?

Is it not a strict requirement, in the English language, to use the reflexive when appropriate?

Comment: In Latin, it is preferable to use the reflexive pronoun when appropriate. Surely, it's always preferable to make the appropriate choice. // Both variants are grammatical and acceptable here. The second is in a more formal register, and is certainly the better choice when the pronoun is better emphasised ('Jill and Ali have found plenty of references supporting their side of the argument, but I have no sources to back myself up.')

Comment: I think it depends on how you parse it.  In one way you are saying “I can’t back myself up with sources.” The other says, “As far as sources that can back me up go, I have none.”

Comment: When you "back yourself up" it sounds more like you're "walking something back".  This is certainly something that is done a lot of late, but it's usually because you have no sources to back up what you just said.

Comment: @HotLicks But isn't "no sources to back me up" a common idiom? To back something (or someone) is to give it support, the way a car seat gives you support while you drive.

Comment: Do you think "I have no sources to back me" is more clear and idiomatic?

Comment: Yep, "back me up" is idiomatic.  "Back myself up" is not.  If it's not a obvious idiom it tends to be interpreted literally -- ie, move backwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is, of course, always preferable to use the reflexive where appropriate.

However, I disagree that the reflexive is appropriate here; as the sentence is constructed, the sources are providing backup to you.  The reflexive is only called for if **you** are providing backup to you.

Comment: +1 Perzackly. Reflexive is called for only when the object is the same as the subject, and the subject of *to back* is *sources*.